# Replacing SQL Server 2005 Express Management Studio with the full version

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation, ssms

I have been running SQL Server 2005 Express Management Studio ("SSMSE"), and I now have a need to install the full version of Management Studio ("SSMS"). This is a known hassle, but I've not found a comprehensive way to carry it out.

At first, I uninstalled SSMSE, and then ran `SqlRun_Tools.msi` to install the toolset. I got this error message:

```
A component that you have specified in the ADD_LOCAL property is already
installed. To upgrade the existing component, refer to the template.ini
and set the UPGRADE property to the name of the component.
```

I had no idea what template.ini was. So I looked around, and decided to uninstall the rest of the minimal installation of SQL Server 2005 Express on my computer by following Microsoft's advice in KB 909967, ["How to uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2005 manually."](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/909967) That bit was very successful.

But when I attempted to run `SqlRun_Tools.msi` again, I faced this mess when the installer was "Preparing Installation Wizard":

```
The setup has encountered an unexpected error in datastore. The action
is SetDialogs. The error is : Source File Name:
...\datastorecachexmlschema.cpp
**** Compiler Timestamp: Fri Jul 29 01:13:50 2005
****    Function Name: DataStoreCacheXMLSchema::initScopeRecord*****Sour...
```

*(but replace the asterisks with box chars, which were probably CR-LF's in the original message)*

This is very frustrating. Does anybody have any advice for installing the full version of SSMS over top of SSMSE? Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't help, but I've had this problem and it's a right PITA.. I actually have a machine I can't install any version of management studio on now, and no amount of registry hacking will make it work :-(

Comment: Do you have any other SQL components installed such as the SNAC, setup or help files?

Comment: I removed all of the SQL2K5 components, as per KB 909967. The only thing I have remaining is SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer Components. I wouldn't think that that would be significant.

Comment: I've verified it... Removing SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer Components doesn't help. Thanks for your help, robsymonds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also installed SQL Management Studio before just using the `SqlRun_Tools.msi` package without any problems but I think if you have previously had any other SQL Server 2005 components installed then you will need to install the Setup Support Files first as this is probably what sets up the component installation sequence. This can be done either by installing from the SQL Server installation media or by running the `sqlsupport.msi` file as described in the Microsoft KB article.

Comment: My colleague ran SqlRun_Tools.msi and installed SSMS with no problems, even though he had SSMSE installed previously. He said that he just uninstalled everything SQL2K5-related before installation.

You answered my question more succinctly then I did. You deserve an Up.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem

Steps

1. Go to Add\remove program
2. unstall SQL server browser
3. Install support files from CD
4. Install SQL_Tools.MSI

Answer (score 0):

Well, I roughly found out what the problem was, based on a [somewhat cryptic resolution](http://groups.google.com.tw/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.tools/browse_thread/thread/ccfcac307f20b7cc) mentioned across a few different forums. This solution suggested that I needed to install Setup Support Files. Maybe it was *reinstall,* since I removed something with the same name when uninstalling SQL2K5 Express. I'm not sure if they were the same files, between the full version and the Express Edition.

I had tried reinstalling SQLXML4, the Native Client, and MSXML6 just to see if I could get beyond the error involving `datastorecachexmlschema.cpp`, and each time, I got the same error again. But I tried the technique mentioned in the above link, and it worked perfectly.

Basically, you insert the CD and run just the first part of the installation process, which installs the installation tools, including Setup Support Files. Then you cancel the rest of the installation process, and run `SqlRun_Tools.msi` instead.

Comment: I recently went through the same thing last week. Good lord could they have made it a bigger pain in the you know what.

Answer (score 0):

I got great results when upgrading 2008 express to 2008 developer by (running setup) first going to Maintenance->Upgrade Edition, and then (since Management Tools etc was still "express" and I mainly needed the Sql Profiler) I also did a complete "new" installation (Installation->"New installation or add features.."), selecting the existing instance and then selecting all features.
No uninstall or command line necessary.
Behaved the same afterwards, just with new features.